# Deploy Strapi with HTTPS on Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, https, virtual-machine, strapi

I have deployed my Strapi application on a VM on Azure but I would like to expose it on port 443 in https. I could see that it was recommended to use nginx as a reverse proxy but is there another way? Could you tell me how you would do it? Do you know a complete tutorial on this subject?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can Deploy Strapi with HTTPS on Azure by following the below steps:

1. Install all the pre-requisites as mentioned in this [document](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/azure.html#azure-install-requirements) like creating VM and setting inbound rules which we want to allow.
2. Next, Logging in and installing Strapi dependencies by following this [steps here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/azure.html#logging-in-and-installing-strapi-dependencies).
3. Then [Creating or cloning our Strapi Project](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/azure.html#creating-or-cloning-our-strapi-project).